# The user data source credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset error when running reports

Tags: reporting-services

I get the following error when trying to run reports:

> The current action cannot be completed. The user data source credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset. Either the user data source credentials are not stored in the report server database, or the user data source is configured not to require credentials but the unattended execution account is not specified. (rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting)

By the way I am running it from VS2010 with SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, I've seen this. You can set the [Credential and Connection Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160330.aspx) such that a report is run impersonating the unattended user account. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156302.aspx) explains how to set up this type of report running. This setup is especially useful if you want to use the credentials inside a dynamic connection string (for example when you need to insert the credentials through a parameter).

If you don't want to run using the unattended user account, you should review your DataSource and connection string as defined in the report. Perhaps play around with the settings and different configurations for the datasource to create a different setup. The above links should be a start for some documentation.

Comment: Thannks Jeroen, I battled with the issue and even created an unattended execution account and added it the Allow users local permission option under Admin tools but it still failed so i just trunked the file and created another one using the design code. Gratefully it worked!

Comment: Also note that even if you have a faulty data source that is unused it will cause report execution to fail. In my case one of the unused data sources had "no credentials required" selected.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, it was because of some deployment parameters.

1. Go to Project Property by Right-clicking at the Project name in Solution Explorer and select Properties.
2. In Configuration Properties > General, change OverwriteDatasets and OverwriteDataSources in Deployment section to **True** for both parameters.
3. Click OK.

Answer (score 2):

in my case, replacing linked server connections with local (fetched from remote locations and stored in local tables)data  connections helped. we also checked this for ALL subreports/linked reports and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me today, it was because I was using the wrong datasource in my report. So I changed the datasource manually in Report manager and it worked. I guess another choice is to redeploy your report with the correct datasource.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me today. I am using Visual Studio 2019 for creating the reports for SQL Server 2014.

One of my reports had an embedded data source, but it was unconfigured/not configured properly. (You can see embedded data sources in the ["Report data" pane](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ab53b7f2-2747-41c3-8849-c948fc7793cc/report-data-pane-missing?forum=sqlreportingservices) under "data sources").

[image: Screenshot showing location of embedded data sources folder]

However, the embedded data source wasn't actually being used. I created the embedded data source earlier for debugging and forgot about it.

After deleting the unused embedded data source, the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

This is from Microsoft:[here](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=8.00&EvtID=rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ErrorStrings.resources)

**User Action**
Change the settings for the current report so that it can run unattended, and then try to create the subscription or other scheduled operation again. Use the following steps to configure a report to run unattended:

**1) Go to the Data Sources properties page of the report that you want to automate.**

**2) For the Connect Using option, select Credentials stored securely in the report server.**

**3) In User Name and Password, type credentials that can be used to access the database. If you are using SQL Server as the data source, the user name must be valid for both logging on to the server and for accessing the database that contains the data for the report.**

**4) If the user name and password are credentials for a Windows account, select Use as Windows Credentials. If the credentials are for a SQL Server user login, do not select this check box.**

Do not select the check box Impersonate the authenticated user after a connection has been made to the data source, regardless of authentication type. This option cannot be used for reports that run unattended.

Comment: the link is broken