# SSRS Error Invalid Source credential setting

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have created a report in SSRS and got it working in the design view. When I publish on the report server I am getting the following error.

The current action cannot be completed. The user data source credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset. Either the user data source credentials are not stored in the report server database, or the user data source is configured not to require credentials but the unattended execution account is not specified. (rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting)

I am using shared datasource and using SQLserver database connection as authentication type. Where else could I have gone wrong and Also let me know what are the settings I would have missed to update

Comment: What type of authentication does your data source use? Also, have you checked that the credentials are correct on the report server? When you deploy a new datasource to the server you may need to configure the credentials again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The user data source credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset error when running reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139777/the-user-data-source-credentials-do-not-meet-the-requirements-to-run-this-report)

Comment: When your publishing your report to the server you are not running it with "your" credentials anymore.. in BIDS set the credentials to use when running the report.

Comment: Hi @Mike - I am using Use Shared data source reference -> Edit -> Use SQL Server Authentication and given the user name and password for the SQL Server.

Comment: Have you checked that the data source on the report server is configured correctly?